# "Messages cannot be resolved to a type" error for an archetype created GWT maven project

Tags: maven, gwt, m2eclipse, m2e

I just created a project following this instructions:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html

It clearly says to run the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin \
   -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.1
```

When imported by Eclipse (Kepler), the project wasn't seen as a maven project. This was fixed by converting to a maven project. So far, "so good".

Then the following error appears in Eclipse:

> Messages cannot be resolved to a type

Why is that? Shouldn't it be working flawlessly?

=== **EDIT** ===

I removed the "*What should I do to fix this?*" question because, actually, I don't "care" how to fix it. What I mean is: I can fix it by adding some libraries or modifying the generated code. The actual question is *Isn't the created projects from archetypes supposed to work flawlessly?*

The problems seems to be related to `i18n`, which, right now, I don't care. Even if the archetype wants to enable it in the initial project, shouldn't it resolve the dependencies and the project setup so I can import it on eclipse without any problems?

The page below doesn't give **any** warning about that:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html

I know, I know, I should be used to this, it happens all the time. :-) For all your effort, thanks.

Comment: Did you run mvn eclipse:eclipse before importing the project (as a maven project) and mvn clean install after ?

Comment: No, I just run the mvn archetype and tried to import, as they instruct to do on their page. 

They clearly say:

_The generated project can then be imported as "existing project" into Eclipse_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error from http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html. Simple as that.

Unfortunately, archetypes created by following their instruction gotta be modified in order to use. Hence, I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use M2Eclipse. 
But according to the error you get I suggest you check that the "target/generated-sources/gwt" folder is on your build path.

Comment: I have no problem to fix the errors getting the build path to include whatever is missing or anything else. I just want to understand the internals of the archetype creation and **why** it doesn't work right away...